# Putty: Network Error: Software caused connection abort

Tags: linux, glibc, rhel, libc

I have RHEL 6.8 Machine installed in a VM. I moved one file `libc.so.6` from `/lib64/` to `/lib64/backup/`. Since then I am not able to connect to that machine through Putty or WinSCP. Both the tools give the same error. **Software caused connection abort.**

As I haven't created this VM, I don't have permission to restart it. But will restarting the machine, solve the issue ? What can be the solution for this situation, except re-installing the OS ?

Comment: Restarting won't solve the issue. You need to access your VM by any other means but SSH and restore `libc.so.6`.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either. It seems that this file is very much important not only for SSH, but also for OS to function properly. Moreover, I shutdown the machine and after that it didn't start at all. While booting, itself it showed that this file has been relocated. After that, there's nothing much you can do, but reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-saving workaround is to reinstall the OS.

**Note :-** Reinstalling the OS will solve the issue, but you'll lose all the installed software and the data. That's why it is a workaround and not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`libc.so.6` is the standard C library and by moving it you borked your system quite well.

The error you get means that SSH connection cannot be established.

All you can do now is access the machine via the console and restore the file in its original position.

Comment: I have this machine in VMWare vCloud Director. It gives the facility to connect to the machine through web browser. After I moved the file, as you know I wasn't able to connect to the machine via SSH, so I tried to connect to the machine through the browser. All I got was a flickering black screen. So, I powered off the machine and then it never, came back up again. So, I had to resintall the OS.